# Construct an example of a function $f (x,y)$ where $f (0,0)=0, \nabla f (0,0)=0, f_{xx}(0, 0)>0, f_{yy}(0, 0)>0$ and has no local minimum at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Construct an explicit example of a function $f (x, y)$ where $f (0, 0) = 0, \nabla f(0, 0) = 0, f_{xx}(0, 0) > 0,
f_{yy}(0, 0) > 0$ but where $f$ does not have a local minimum at $(0, 0)$. Hint: first define such a function
in polar coordinates and then convert to cartesian coordinates.

Function I have chosen: $f(x,y)=10xy+x^2+y^2$
This satisfies the conditions $f (0, 0) = 0, \nabla f(0, 0) = 0, f_{xx}(0, 0) > 0,
f_{yy}(0, 0) > 0$ with $f_{xx}(0, 0) = 2$ and $f_{yy}(0, 0) = 2$

$f_{xy}(0, 0)=10$ and discriminant $D = f_{xx}f_{yy} − f^2_{xy}$ so $D=4-100=-96$ and as $D<0$ it is a saddle point.

Does this function satisfy what the problem is asking for?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: added my work @Henry

Answer (score 3):

Try $f(x,y)=x^{2}-100xy+y^{2}$ , Then $f(0,0)=0$ , $\bigtriangledown f(0,0)$=$0$ and $f_{xx}=2$, $f_{yy}=2$,

BUT B=$f_{xy}=-100$ and hence $AC-B^{2}<0$, so $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: The similar example is in the question. Maybe it wasn't.